# Iterating through a list of urls and grabbing selected text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi I'm trying to write a script that will scrape specified information from a list of urls that in this case are job listings, and then with the specified information (from html) on each job listing page, write that to a file. The part about writing to a file I'm not too concerned with right now, I'm more focused on being able extract desired info from a specified link. I've written this code to create a list of the urls of interest:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Get links for all open listings
mainpage = requests.get('https://www.digitalmarketplace.service.gov.uk/digital-outcomes-and-specialists/opportunities?q=&statusOpenClosed=open%27%27%27')
soup = BeautifulSoup(mainpage.text, 'html.parser')
link_list = []

for opps in soup.findAll('li', class_='app-search-result'):
    links = opps.h2.a.get('href')
    open_links = ('https://www.digitalmarketplace.service.gov.uk/%27+links')
    link_list.append(open_links)
# print(link_list[25])
```

This works fine as I can select a desired link by index. For the next part I'm trying to write a for loop that will iterate over each link in link_list and for the respective link then grab the specified information.

```
# Write for loop hat grabs specified information
for idx, item in enumerate(link_list[0:]):
    open_opps = requests.get(open_links)
    open_soup = BeautifulSoup(open_opps.text, 'html.parser')
    closing_date = open_soup.findAll(class_="govuk-summary-listvalue")[2].text
    summary = open_soup.findAll(class_="govuk-summary-listvalue")[3].text

print(closing_date[25])
```

In the above code I tried to extract the closing date of the 24th job listing however I received an error:

```
closing_date = open_soup.findAll(class_="govuk-summary-listvalue")[2].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm wondering how I can go about writing this so I can extract specified info such as the closing date of the 2nd job listing. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: List indexes start at 0 so if you want the closing date of the 2nd job listing you need to use an index of 1. Tip: when you encounter a "IndexError: list index out of range" it might be useful to print the list and the index to see what went wrong (in this case there's no need to print the index because it's a constant).

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention the indexes on the closing date and summary equate to the index of the tag in the html of their page. So there are multiple 'govuk-summary-listvalue' classes in the html of the job listing pages

Comment: `'https://www.digitalmarketplace.service.gov.uk/%27+links'` this url is not valid you must use c string formatting or f string for example : `"https://www.digitalmarketplace.service.gov.uk{}".format(links)`

Answer (score 0):

While Parsing closing date you are using wrong xpath class

```
 closing_date = open_soup.findAll(class_="govuk-summary-list__value")[2].text
 summary = open_soup.findAll(class_="govuk-summary-list__value")[3].text
```

instead of `govuk-summary-listvalue` use `govuk-summary-list__value` as class value